# How to set up multiple images in azure pipelines

Tags: python, azure, azure-pipelines

I want to set up my CI in Azure-pipelines to run my tests in:

- Python 3.6 / Linux
- Python 3.7 / Linux
- Python 3.6 / Windows
- Python 3.7 / Windows

I see that I can test with different Python versions easily by using `matrix`, but I'm guessing if there is a simple way to do the same with the images. I think it might be possible to use templates for it, but I'd like to keep everything simple and in a single file if that's an option.

This is what I've got so far for testing py3.6/py3.7 in Linux:

```
- job: 'Test'
  pool:
    vmImage: 'Ubuntu 16.04'
  strategy:
    matrix:
      Python36:
        python.version: '3.6'
      Python37:
        python.version: '3.7'

  steps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '$(python.version)'
      architecture: 'x64'

  - script: python -m unittest discover tests
    displayName: 'Run unittest tests'
```

Comment: As far as I know no any other simple ways, the solution you mentioned is enough.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is no way to implement this with a matrix-like way (it should be implemented at some point in the future). The two options are:

- Using a [template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=vsts#job-templates) to define the steps in a separate file, and call the template with different images
- Have one job for each `vmImage`, and repeat the steps in each

Source: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/1855#issuecomment-425191025